# Texmaker - ! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found

Tags: packages, texmaker, animate, preamble

I need to include `animate` package in my text. When I tried that, I got an error:

> LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.

So after that I also inserted package `l3backend` into my preamble, which is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{l3backend}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{animate}
```

but it still does not work, I have the same error:

> ​! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend.sty' not found.

Please can anybody help me? I am working in Texmaker, using the most recent version 5.0.4.

Comment: I am sorry, but it does not. I´ve already had a look at it and I am not sure how to run tlmgr in the Texmaker?

Comment: Not in TeXMaker (that's only the editor). Do you use TeXLive or MiKTeX? (also, `\usepackage{l3backend}` is wrong, you can remove that line).